# Wireless device does not work on Compaq Presario V2000

Tags: compaq, presario

I changed to Ubuntu 14.04 in this Compaq Presario V2000, but the wireless device (PCI) does not work. I already installed the drivers using `ndiswrapper`. But it still does not work.

What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please expand on your question further? What wireless card are you using, was this card working on a prior system (before you installed Ubuntu?) What are some outputs? You could look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into to help

Answer (score 0):

You likely have Broadcom chip, confirm this with

```
lspci -vvnn
```

and look for the "Network controller" section, then find the chip on the first line after the {14e4,...)  See http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43 for the correct driver, but it's probably b43.
These days, the b43 driver works fine after you add the firmware, so add package linux-firmware-nonfree for any chip other than a 4306 rev before 3
For the older 4306 revs, use the b43legacy driver.
Uninstall any ndiswrapper or other Broadcom drivers, and things should work.